# C# - Linked list implementation

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

Ok, so im working on a programming exercise where i have to write my own implementation for a FIFO linkedlist. I have a set of unittests that im trying to satisfy. My implementation so far works reasonably well. The problem im facing however is with the Next property.

In the Unittests they want to be able to call the Next property like this.

> List.Next.Next.Value
>
> List.Next.Value

etc. My implementation returns the entire class instance if someone calls Next, however when someone calls Next in multiple statements then the second statement will no longer have a fresh instance and the test fails.

My implementation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SimpleLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public class Node
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public Node Next { get; set; }
    }

    private Node First = null;
    private Node Last = null;

    public SimpleLinkedList(T value)
    {
        AddNode(value);
    }

    public SimpleLinkedList(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            AddNode(value);
        }
    }

    public T Value {
        get {
            return First != null ? First.Data : default(T);
        }
    }

    public SimpleLinkedList<T> Next {
        get {
            if (First.Next != null)
            {
                First = First.Next;
                return this;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public SimpleLinkedList<T> Add(T value)
    {
        AddNode(value);
        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var current = First;
        while (current.Next != null)
        {
            yield return First.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    void AddNode(T value)
    {
        Node _newNode = new Node() { Data = value };
        if (First == null)
        {
            First = _newNode;
            Last = First;
        }
        else
        {
            Last.Next = _newNode;
            Last = Last.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

Failing unittest:

```
[Fact]
public void From_enumerable()
{
    var list = new SimpleLinkedList<int>(new[] { 11, 7, 5, 3, 2 });

    Assert.Equal(11, list.Value);
    Assert.Equal(7, list.Next.Value);
    Assert.Equal(5, list.Next.Next.Value);
    Assert.Equal(3, list.Next.Next.Next.Value);
    Assert.Equal(2, list.Next.Next.Next.Next.Value);
}
```

The unittests fails on the assert 5. Because in the statement before it Next has allready been called and the state of the object has been altered.

Ive tried keeping an internal 'Current' property to return instead of the First. But then im running into the problem, how do i know when to restart Current?
Im at a loss how to proceed from here.

Comment: Looks like the `SimpleLinkedList<T>` class should itself be a node, otherwise `list.Next` makes no sense, semantically speaking. Get rid of the `Node` class altogether.

Comment: Are you sure that SimpleLinkedList<T> Next should return SimpleLinkedList not a Node?

Comment: Yes the signature for the Next property was allready defined, so i need to return an instance of SimpleLinkedList<T>